# Connect oracledb using node protractor js

Tags: javascript, node.js, oracle, protractor

I'm trying to connect the oracle db using Protractor JS file. I know using **oracledb** module we can able to connect. But the installation of oracledb have more dependencies, Hence I can't able to use that one.

I have tried with **oracledb-pd** node but getting the below error:

```
 Error: The specified path is invalid.
   \\?\..\..\node_modules\oracledb-pb\build\Release\oracledb.node
```

If there any other way to connect the oracle db using node protractor js file.

Answer (score 1):

Install oracle instant client and Adminitrator. Then Set OCI_INC_DIR and OCI_LIB_DIR path in system enviornment variable.
Run command prompt as Administrator and try again oracledb installation.